# Is there an Excel formula or command that displays cells that have been incorporated in a formula?

Tags: vba, excel-formula

If a cell is used in a formula, we can see that it is highlighted (in a color) when the cell containing the formula referencing it is selected. Is there some way to permanently highlight if a cell has been referenced at all in the workbook? Any sort of suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: SORTA...if you move over to the formula ribbon, and look in the audit formula section i think its call, you can do trace dependents and trace precendents, and it will place arrows pointing to the respective cells from that sheet.

Comment: The other possibility might to do it through VBA.  The method is beyond me at the moment but adding a VBA tag to your question might help.  You will need to show what you have tried though most likely if you want to get some more help.